# Trouble using a bubble sort to sort from highest to lowest

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sorting

my program reads in a text file of 5 grades from each student, and uses a menu to select if the user wants the maximum, minimum, or average values. Everything works as intended, but the grade values are not listed from highest to lowest. Here is my bubble sort function:

```
void bubbleSort(vector<Student>& grades, bool(*doSwapTest)(Student &, 
                Student &))
{
    bool didSwap = false;

    for (int i = grades.size() - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        didSwap = false;                    // we assume no swaps
        for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
        {
            if ((*doSwapTest)(grades[j], grades[j + 1]))
            {
                swap(grades[j], grades[j + 1]);
                didSwap = true;
            }
        } // end of inner for loop
        if (!didSwap) break;
    } // end of outer for loop
}
```

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdEiF.png) of my output, notice how the letter grades are not sorted. I have tried changing the > and < operators inside my swap statements but it doesn't seem to change the ordering of the grades.

My program returns no errors, could someone please give me some advice on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: What is the `for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)` supposed to do? There aren't many values between 0 and 1...

Comment: Technically there are infinite values between 0 and 1 but I see your point. 
Is that causing my problem or did you just want to point that out?

Comment: @jacobbullon: Think about it.

Comment: Got it. Thank you fellas.

Comment: It must be extremely unusual to loop over 1 value, so it is a bit odd at least. Not sure, but I can imagine that `j < i`, or something similar, could be more useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `(int j = 0; j < 1; j++)` to `int j = 0; j < i; j++`, which fixed my problem.